# how to read objects continuously

Tags: java, serialization

I have written Objects into a .bin file, i am trying to read them into the console, but this

```
try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.bin"))){
    for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null)
        System.out.println(s);
}catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

gives me an error on the second line in the increment of the for loop : *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Ser to boolean*, how can i do this ?

Comment: What do you think `for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null)` does?

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null)
```

After the first `;`:

```
; s = (Ser)ois.readObject();
```

Supposed to give a `boolean` result.

Maybe what you really want is something like:

```
for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null; s = (Ser)ois.readObject())
```

Comment: This won't set s to the next object after looping though, you'd have to do that in the loop itself then.

Answer (score 1):

You have your loop clauses mismatched.  It's

```
for(declarations; exit_check; increment)
```

In the pattern you're trying to use, you would normally do something like

```
for(Ser ser = null; (ser = (Ser)ois.readObject()) != null; /*blank*/) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: ok that was a silly mistake, that helped but now i have the right output followed by an "EOFException"

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s = (Ser)ois.readObject(); s!=null)
```

Should be

```
try {
    for(Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject();; s = (Ser)ois.readObject())
    {
         //Code
    }
} catch(EOFException ex)
{
    //EOF found
}
```

Instead.
In a for loop the condition should be on the second line, not on the third.

Because javac is looking for a condition at your second line and finds `s`, an instance of `Ser`, it says `s` cannot be converted to a `boolean`.

@EJP :

> Contrary to what everybody seems to think here, readObject() does not return null at end of stream. It throws EOFException.

@EJP is right about the EOF, I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: You should edit your answer to remove all the irrelevance.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is wrong anyway, no point in trying to fix it. Contrary to what everybody seems to think here, `readObject()` does not return `null` at end of stream. It throws `EOFException.` So that is what you have to test for:

```
try( ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.bin"))){
    for(;;) {
        Ser s = (Ser)ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
} catch (EOFException exc) {
    // end of stream: OK
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You easily can use a null value to indicate the end of a section in your file, but I agree that that's probably not what OP is going for.  However I wouldn't really consider yours better style (catching an exception in the normal control flow).  It'd be better to either know in advance how many objects to read or to serialize a list structure.

Comment: @Mark Peters The method throws `EOFException` because `null` is an in-band value. You could only use `null` if you're prepared to lose null as a legal value elsewhere in the file, and only if you can guarantee that the file will never be closed without its trailing null. Neither constraint is realistic, nor any constraint that files must start with their own number of elements. The method is already designed to throw EOFException, ergo it must be caught. Period.